# TerminateThread function (Windows) How to exit from thread nicely that is waiting for registry key value change?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

  // this is how I end thread now
  if (objRegEv->hThread != NULL) TerminateThread(objRegEv->hThread,0);

  // sending commands to application (not mine), 
  //after command execution application (not mine) will wait for user click. 
  //When user makes that click, application (not mine) stores result in registry.
  objIapr->IaprClick(0, 230);

  // making thread that waits for registy key change event
  objRegEv->Enable();
}

HANDLE REG_EV_MK::Enable(){
  RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, pathToSetenv, 0, KEY_NOTIFY | KEY_READ, &hKey);
  hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc,NULL,0,&dwThreadID);
  return hThread;
}

DWORD WINAPI REG_EV_MK::ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam){
  RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(hKey, TRUE, REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, NULL, FALSE);

  /* In this section I am reading some registry 
  key values and storing them in some_parameters*/

  msg(some_parameters);
  return 0;
}

//calling necessary function depending on some_parameters values
//some of those functions will call Enable() function again in that way  making an other thread
void REG_EV_MK::msg(wchar_t* ready, wchar_t* name){
  if (wcscmp(name, L"iapr230step1") == 0){

  // not sure, maybe there should be an other checking or
  // maybe I should use RegCloseKey(hKey) in order to avoid a deadlock.
   if (Enable() != NULL)
         objIapr->IaprClick(1, 230, ready);
}
```

Main idea:
 I click a button, then using DDEML I am sending commands to application (not mine). It executes those commands and in the end makes changes to specific key in windows registry (that means all commands have been executed). When key has been changed, (depending on key's new value) I am sending other commands to that application.

Comment: Use fAsynchronous = TRUE, provide an event handle. Then wait for this event and for another event (stop event). To stop waiting, set stop event from another thread. See also: WaitForMultipleObjects

Comment: The docs are pretty clear on this. If you don't want it to block, don't ask it to block!

Comment: @Alex-Farber WaitForMultipleObjects with 2 events solved the problem. Thank You! I would accept it as an answer if it was not a comment...